# Akka configuration overwritting

Tags: configuration, akka, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to overwrite Akka configuration in my application. I have created additional lib for the application, which also has application.conf file as it uses Akka. So I have 2 of them:

```
application.conf in my lib: 
my-conf {
 something = 1
}

application.conf in my app, which uses the lib:
something-else = "foo"
my-conf {
 something = 1000
}
```

When I'm running the app from Intellij Idea, everything is fine, and lib configuration is being overwritten. To load the config in my app I'm using simple `ConfigFactory.load()` operation. 
But when I create a jar of my app with `mvn clean compile assembly:single` and try to run it with this command: `java -Xmx4048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xss256K -classpath myApp.jar com.myapp.example.MyMain` I get error:

```
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'something-else'
```

So I decided to rename the conf file in my app, and load it in such way:

```
  val defConfig = ConfigFactory load
  val myConfig = ConfigFactory load "myconf"
  val combined = myConfig.withFallback(defConfig)
  val config = ConfigFactory load combined
```

It finds missing settings, but unfortunately config from my app doesn't override config in my lib.
In my lib I load config in default way: `val settings = ConfigFactory load`
Also, "my-conf.something" is an important setting, and I'd like to overwrite it from my app.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Also, I thought there could be an issue how I create the jar:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.myapp.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <finalName>loadtest</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>dist-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The snippet you show for loading your config looks strange: `combined` should be the one you want, what are you using `config` for?

Comment: According to Akka Configuration docs example, they use `complete` (`config` in my case) to build ActorSystem:

`// put the result in between the overrides
// (system props) and defaults again
Config complete =
  ConfigFactory.load(combined);
// create ActorSystem
ActorSystem system =
  ActorSystem.create("myname", complete);`

link: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html

Comment: In your example this "sandwiching" has already occurred, twice. Rereading your post suggests that you are not actually using the config derived as shown above within your lib, as you say that the lib uses `ConfigFactory.load()` internally; that would then be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, your library should create file called `reference.conf`. According to https://github.com/typesafehub/config :

> libraries should use a `Config` instance provided by the app, if any,
>   and use `ConfigFactory.load()` if no special Config is provided.
>   Libraries should put their defaults in a `reference.conf` on the
>   classpath.

So, i suggest putting a `reference.conf` into your library first, to make it clear that it is default configuration, and you won't need to have a `withFallback` - typesafe-config will handle it for you.

**Update:** I don't remember how `maven-assembly-plugin` works - it may combine all of jar files and resources in a single file, meaning that `lib/src/main/resources/application.conf` will be overwritten by `app/src/main/resources/application.conf` in your case - so yet another reason to use `reference.conf`.

Comment: I see your point and I'm feeling blind, that I missed these lines in documentation. But for some reason, after packaging I'm getting error: 
`Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'`. This means, that my lib doesn't see akka default conf or something like that. Anyway, I found another solution (which is ugly, I think): if lib conf will stay application.conf and I will run my jar with `java -Dconfig.file=application.conf ...` - everything works as it should be. Will try to make it work right with your solution

Comment: So, if my update is correct, then `akka-actor`'s  `reference.conf` may be overwritten by another dependencies' `reference.conf` - i.e. from akka-testkit, or the spray-can, or any other library that uses typesafe-config library. I'd look into that. As you run in non-assembled mode using IDE just fine, i believe that's the case.

Comment: I totally agree with you, that is the right approach. By the way you gave good examples, I'll take a look on a spray can lib, may be I will find something that I'm doing wrong. Also, I will look through the assembly plugin docs, probably I missed sometihng. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Straight from akka documentation:

If you are using Maven to package your application, you can also make use of the Apache Maven Shade Plugin support for **Resource Transformers** to merge all the reference.confs on the build classpath into one.

This resolved the issue for me.

```
 <transformers>
  <transformer
   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
   <resource>reference.conf</resource>
  </transformer>
  <transformer
   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
   <manifestEntries>
    <Main-Class>akka.Main</Main-Class>
   </manifestEntries>
  </transformer>
</transformers>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's right! Just in order to add a bit more information related to that reference.conf I would say that you should go to:
Akka Documentation: http://akka.io/docs/?_ga=1.90177882.150089464.1402497958
, pick the version you are using and in it look for General->Configuration
inside that page look for 'Listing of the Reference Configuration', that's all the content you may need for that reference.conf. In my case I just copied it all.

Hope it helps to save sometime!